# how to send an Object like I can send String using PrintWriter

Tags: java, client-server, draw, send

Hi I am working on simple client server aplication in which clients can draw pictures and chatting using text, I send text when pressing button, and I'd like to send in the same way List of Object called ColorPointSize which refers to list of points, colours and size of points which are then drawn on a Panel. Can I do it in as simple way as when sending strings via PrintWriter or shall I convert them toString() and then somehow convert it back to ColorPointSize or use serialization, but I don't really have idea how to do it I'm begginer to Java and I feel confused.

Here are some parts of the code :
Sending message to server

```
private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String nothing = "";
    if ((inputTextArea.getText()).equals(nothing)) {
        inputTextArea.setText("");
        inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    } else {
        try {
           writer.println(username + ":" + inputTextArea.getText() + ":" + "Chat");
           //  here i want to send also an object of type shall i do it via changing toString() and then somehow converting it or what ???
           Date now = new Date();
           String temp=inputTextArea.getText();
           s_archiwum="\n"+s_archiwum+"\n"+now+" "+temp+"\n";
           writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            chatTextArea.append("Message was not sent. \n");
        }
        inputTextArea.setText("");
        inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    }
    inputTextArea.setText("");
    inputTextArea.requestFocus();
}
```

Adding name of connected user to online users list I'd like to add ColorPointSize in similar way .

```
public void userAdd(String data) {
    String message, add = ": :Connect", done = "Server: :Done", name = data;
    outputPane.append("Before " + name + " added. \n");
    onlineUsers.add(name);
    outputPane.append("After " + name + " added. \n");
    String[] tempList = new String[(onlineUsers.size())];
    onlineUsers.toArray(tempList);

    for (String token : tempList) {

        message = (token + add);
        tellEveryone(message);
    }
    tellEveryone(done);
}
```

Drawing method: (cps is a list of objects of type ColorPointSize)

```
private void drawRoundRectangles(Graphics2D g2d) {
    int x, y, x2, y2;
    synchronized (cps) {
        for (ColorPointSize p : cps) {
            g2d.setColor(p.color);
            x = (int) p.getX();
            y = (int) p.getY();
            x2 = (int) p.getX() - 1;
            y2 = (int) p.getY() - 1;

            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2);

            g2d.fillRoundRect(x, y, p.size, p.size, p.size, p.size);

            g2d.drawLine(x, y, x2, y2); // connectin' points wit' line

        }
    }
}
```

ColorPointSize class (just in case)

```
package paintalk;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

public class ColorPointSize {
    public Color color;
    public Point point;
    public int size;

    public ColorPointSize(Color c, Point p, int s) {
        this.color = c;
        this.point = p;
        this.size = s;
    }

    ColorPointSize(Point p) {
        this.point = p;
    }

    double getX() {
        return point.getX();
    }

    double getY() {
        return point.getY();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to serializing and deserializing data, where you've presumably created the `PrintWriter` to write to some kind of `OutputStream` (perhaps even `System.out`, which is just one convenient `OutputStream`).

The package `java.io` actually provides a neat set of classes: `java.io.ObjectInputStream` and `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`. You can use these as a pair to send arbitrary Java objects, as long as they add "implements Serializable" to their class definition--implementing "Serializable" isn't actually adding any methods, it's just used as a special marker for Java to allow boiling the object down to its low-level bytes, and just works as long as each item within your object is also defined with "implements Serializable". Try the following example by naming it Test.java and running "java Test"; I modified your ColorPointSize class with "implements Serializable" but it's otherwise unchanged:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

class ColorPointSize implements Serializable {
  public Color color;
  public Point point;
  public int size;

  public ColorPointSize(Color c, Point p, int s){
    this.color=c;
    this.point=p;
    this.size=s;
  }
  ColorPointSize(Point p){
    this.point=p;
  }

  double getX(){
    return point.getX();
  }

  double getY(){
    return point.getY();
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ColorPointSize foo = new ColorPointSize(
        new Color(123, 222, 111), new Point(42, 24), 50);
    System.out.println(foo.color);
    System.out.println(foo.point);
    System.out.println(foo.size);

    ObjectOutputStream fout = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(new File("foo.dat")));
    fout.writeUnshared(foo);
    fout.close();

    ObjectInputStream fin = new ObjectInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(new File("foo.dat")));
    ColorPointSize bar = (ColorPointSize) fin.readUnshared();
    fin.close();

    System.out.println(bar.color);
    System.out.println(bar.point);
    System.out.println(bar.size);
  }
}
```

If you run the example, you'll see that this example successfully writes all the internals of your ColorPointSize instance to a file, and then reads it back in, recovering all its settings. Note that this wouldn't work if you try to put something that's fundamentally not Serializable inside your ColorPointSize class, such as a Socket object.

Now, instead of wrapping the ObjectOutputStream around a FileOutputStream like in the example, you could wrap it around any other type of OutputStream, such as one provided by a network socket, which you'll presumably be using if writing a Client/Server application.

In general, writing the raw objects may be convenient, but it may not always be the most efficient way. Likewise, sometimes your class just can't be directly Serializable, and you'll want better control. A common pattern is to simply add methods to your class for serializing and deserializing, along the lines of the following:

```
class ColorPointSize {
  public Color color;
  public Point point;
  public int size;

  public void deserializeFrom(DataInputStream in) {
    this.color = new Color(in.readInt(), in.readInt(), in.readInt());
    this.point = new Point(in.readInt(), in.readInt());
    this.size = in.readInt();
  }

  public void serializeTo(DataOutputStream out) {
    out.writeInt(color.getRed());
    out.writeInt(color.getGreen());
    out.writeInt(color.getBlue());
    out.writeInt(point.getX());
    out.writeInt(point.getY());
    out.writeInt(size);
  }
}
```

Or more efficiently:

```
class ColorPointSize {
  public Color color;
  public Point point;
  public int size;

  public void deserializeFrom(DataInputStream in) {
    this.color = new Color(in.readInt());
    this.point = new Point(in.readInt(), in.readInt());
    this.size = in.readInt();
  }

  public void serializeTo(DataOutputStream out) {
    out.writeInt(color.getRGB());
    out.writeInt(point.getX());
    out.writeInt(point.getY());
    out.writeInt(size);
  }
}
```

Then, you can use `new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo.dat"))` instead of `new ObjectOutputStream`, and likewise `new DataInputStream` on the input side. In general, you'll want to think of both the input and output side of each communication channel as a pair, and then you can really choose whatever strategy you want to save your data into a stream in some manner that you can easily recover on the other end. In the above example, you could have just as easily used some combinations of "toString()" methods if you want your serialized format to be human-readable.